# Can someone explain "infinitely often" by simple example?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the Borel-Cantelli lemma, however, I cannot understand what exactly is "infinitely often". Can someone please explain "infinitely often" by a simple example?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has so many downvotes... It's a simple question, but I don't see an issue with that. I guess you could argue it's "low effort", but I suspect it's hard to find answers for basic questions like this by googling around, since most people take it for granted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider an infinite sequence of coin tosses $HTHTHT...$. Here both heads and tails show up infinitely often. Contrast this with the sequence $HHTTTTTTTTT...$, where tails show up infinitely often, but heads does not.

If $E_n$ is the event that the $n$th coin flip was heads, in the first example we would say that the event $E_n$ occurs for infinitely many $n$, since $E_n$ is true for $n = 1,3,5,7,...$ However, in the second example, we would *not* have $E_n$ for infinitely many $n$. Indeed in the second example $E_n$ would only be true for $n=1,2$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer above with use of precise definitions:
Consider the process of flipping coins infinitely many times.

Let's first define our probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$:

$\Omega$ is the set of all $\omega$ such that $\omega \in \{0, 1\}$, i.e: the set of all infinite vectors consisting of zeros and ones. In this case a 1 corresponds to heads, and a 0 to tails.

$\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $\Omega$. Defining it is a bit wordy, but here it is, along with the definition of P:

Let $B$ be the set of all finite vectors b consisting of zeros and ones, i.e. $B=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{b | b \in \{0, 1\}^n\}$.

For a given $b$, define $W_b$ as the set of $\omega$'s in $\Omega$ such that the first $|b|$ elements of $\omega$ match the first $|b|$ elements of $b$, i.e. $W_b = \{\omega \in \Omega | w_i = b_i \text{ for all } i \in \{1, \cdots, n\}\}$

We define P such that $P(W_b) = 2^{-|b|}$. That is, the probability of getting $n$ heads in a row is $2^{-n}$. Or, in terms of measure theory, the set of all infinite $\omega$'s which match $b$ in the first $|b|$ values has measure $|2^{-n}|$.

Now, let $W = \{W_b | b \in B\}$. We define:
$\mathcal{F}$ = $\sigma(W)$, i.e: $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma algebra generated by $W$.

Let $A_n$ denote the event that the n'th throw is a heads. More specifically, this means that
$A_n = \{\omega | w_n = 1\}$

We are now ready to ask: what does $\{A_n \text{ } i.o.\}$ mean?
$\{A_n \text{ } i.o.\}$ is the set of all $\omega$ so that $\omega$ belongs to infinitely many $A_n$. That is, $\{A_n \text{ } i.o.\}$ is the set of all vectors $\omega$ that have infinitely many ones in them.

In terms of our example, $\{A_n \text{ } i.o.\}$ is the event that we flip heads infinitely many times (not necessarily in a row).

Some questions one might ask are, what is $P(\{A_n \text{ } i.o.\})$? It turns out that in this case, it is 1 (according to the Borel Cantelli lemma). But this is not always true.